# Reading DataTable from Webservice to android

Tags: android, web-services, datatable

I built Web service that reads from Sql Server. I have two methods: (OpenAccount)write name and phone in the database and the (SelectInfo) read Informations according to names.
I used this web service in my android application and i can use OpenAccount correctly. but SelectInfo will return Datatable in web service how can i receive datatable in android.
This is my code that uses OpenAccount . Can u help me what do i need to add to use SelectInfo method:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't u use JSON?

Comment: json will not help me when i want to connect to sql server remotely 
there will be some shared information between users